# Problem with exam document class

Tags: exam

In this document class "exam" a question has 6.5 points and another has 4.5 points.

Why do the scores 6.5 and 4.5  not appear in the table? And also the sum of the points is wrong. I would like the scores to appear in the table. Furthermore, there are 5.5.5 numbers that I have not written. How can I correct my script?

Thanks a lot.[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}

  \usepackage{enumerate}



\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ExamResetAfterFirstRun}{%
  \renewcommand*{\PgInfo@write}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}%
}
\makeatother

\pointpoints{Punto}{Punti}
\bonuspointpoints{punto (bonus)}{punti (bonus)}






\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
      \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
      #2
    }%
  }%
  \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
}






\begin{document}

\large 



\newcounter{copynum} % copy number, to be printed in the footer 
\newcounter{NumCopy} % how many copies do we want?
\setcounter{NumCopy}{1} % we want 3
\whiledo{\thecopynum<\theNumCopy}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1} % start numbering pages for the current copy at 1
  \addtocounter{copynum}{1} % the number of the current copy
  \setcounter{question}{1} % make questions start at 1 again
  \setcounter{part}{1}  % make parts start at 1 again
  \setcounter{numquestions}{0}
  \setcounter{numpoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numbonuspoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubsubparts}{0}
  \ifnum\value{copynum}>1 %
    \ExamResetAfterFirstRun
  \fi




\begin{center}

Institute bla bla bla

\begin{minipage}{.40\textwidth}
\centering
{\textbf{TEST}}
\end{minipage}


\end{center}
\vspace{0.2in}
\noindent {\makebox[\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill} }

  \begin{questions}



\question[10] Question 1 bla bla bla
\question[6.5] Question 2 bla bla bla
\question[4.5] Question 3 bla bla bla


    \end{questions} 
{
 { 
  \begin{center}
  \hqword{EX}
  \hpword{Pt}
  \bhpword{Bonus Pt:}
  \htword{\textbf{Tot}}
  \hsword{tot 2}
  \cellwidth{1.0em}
  \gradetable[h][questions]
  \end{center}
  \begin{center}
 {\footnotesize  bla bla bla}
  \end{center}}
  }




}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change .5 to `\half`

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ExamResetAfterFirstRun}{%
  \renewcommand*{\PgInfo@write}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}%
}
\makeatother

\pointpoints{Punto}{Punti}
\bonuspointpoints{punto (bonus)}{punti (bonus)}

\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
      \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
      #2
    }%
  }%
  \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
}
\begin{document}
\large 
\newcounter{copynum} % copy number, to be printed in the footer 
\newcounter{NumCopy} % how many copies do we want?
\setcounter{NumCopy}{1} % we want 3
\whiledo{\thecopynum<\theNumCopy}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1} % start numbering pages for the current copy at 1
  \addtocounter{copynum}{1} % the number of the current copy
  \setcounter{question}{1} % make questions start at 1 again
  \setcounter{part}{1}  % make parts start at 1 again
  \setcounter{numquestions}{0}
  \setcounter{numpoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numbonuspoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubsubparts}{0}
  \ifnum\value{copynum}>1 %
    \ExamResetAfterFirstRun
  \fi

\begin{center}

Institute bla bla bla

\begin{minipage}{.40\textwidth}
\centering
{\textbf{TEST}}
\end{minipage}

\end{center}
\vspace{0.2in}
\noindent {\makebox[\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill} }

\begin{questions}
\question[10] Question 1 bla bla bla
\question[6\half] Question 2 bla bla bla
\question[4\half] Question 3 bla bla bla

\end{questions} 
{
 { 
  \begin{center}
  \hqword{EX}
  \hpword{Pt}
  \bhpword{Bonus Pt:}
  \htword{\textbf{Tot}}
  \hsword{tot 2}
  \cellwidth{1.0em}
  \gradetable[h][questions]
  \end{center}
  \begin{center}
 {\footnotesize  bla bla bla}
  \end{center}}
  }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]